# Set padding on all columns in grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a grid with bootstrap 3 there is looking like the below image. It is not possible for me to use Bootstrap 4, since it is a webshop with over 100.000 products, so the backend developers did not change it yet.

[image]

My problem is regarding the padding. All around the columns I would like to have a `padding:15px;`. At the moment I am giving each column the `class="top-pad-d"`. But I am getting problems when I look at a mobile:

[image]

So to make my padding work, I now have to make a padding inside a media query, fx with the `class="top-pad-m"`. But it is getting very complicated to control and weird.

For a single column the code will be:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
     <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive top-pad-d top-pad-m"></a>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can write some code there is saying - around all columns should there be `15px padding`?

Please notice that I cannot set `padding:15px;` on all small columns, since they then will have a `padding:30px;`, because there is 2 rows on top of each other.

```css
.row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 7.5px;
    padding-left: 7.5px;
}
.padding-y {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    border: 1px solid #ebecf0;
}
.top-pad-d {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Section 4 -->
<div class="section padding-y">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x427" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive column-top-pad"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive column-top-pad"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive column-top-pad"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive column-top-pad"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you want margin instead of padding, However the code as it is works as expected, You probably have some styles overriding the padding you added

Comment: I don't know if i understand the problem see example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ce5k3byg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a full css solution: you will not have to alter the DOM anymore. To get to the result you want I've added `padding: 7.5px` to every column. Now in-between every column there is a distance of `7.5px + 7.5px = 15px`. However, the outer edges still have a padding of `7.5px`. That is why I've added a padding of `7.5px` to the `.row` class. So now, there's a distance of `15px` around every column.

```css
.row [class*="col-"] {
  padding: 7.5px;
}

.row {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 7.5px !important;
}

.padding-y {
  margin-left: 15px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Section 4 -->
<div class="section padding-y">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x427" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/196x210" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very good solution. I can just see that the css class "row" is affecting all the page, so I need to set a prefix on the row? If i fx set `chi-row` on the CSS and HTML it is not working anymore. How can that be?

Comment: @MK-DK hmm not sure what the prefix “chi” would do. Its probably affecting the entire page now because there’s only that row is the content of the page.